# a website background similar to canva

Tags: visual-web-developer-2010

okay so i am a beginner in web coding

so the thing is i want my website to look like this in the background of my website whenever i move the mouse over the background the wallpaper must appear for example exactly like the one in this site but i just don't know how to do that if someone will help me out with a code or some sort please

the link to the example is here

should i do it with the mouse over or javascript and how

https://www.canva.com/

Answer (score 2):

I tried like this, it works for me

```js
var image = document.querySelector('img');
var imageCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var imageCanvasContext = imageCanvas.getContext('2d');
var lineCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var lineCanvasContext = lineCanvas.getContext('2d');
var pointLifetime = 1000;
var points = [];

if (image.complete) {
  start();
} else {
  image.onload = start;
}

/**
 * Attaches event listeners and starts the effect.
 */
function start() {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvases);
  document.body.appendChild(imageCanvas);
  resizeCanvases();
  tick();
}

/**
 * Records the user's cursor position.
 *
 * @param {!MouseEvent} event
 */
function onMouseMove(event) {
  points.push({
    time: Date.now(),
    x: event.clientX,
    y: event.clientY
  });
}

/**
 * Resizes both canvases to fill the window.
 */
function resizeCanvases() {
  imageCanvas.width = lineCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  imageCanvas.height = lineCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

/**
 * The main loop, called at ~60hz.
 */
function tick() {
  // Remove old points
  points = points.filter(function(point) {
    var age = Date.now() - point.time;
    return age < pointLifetime;
  });

  drawLineCanvas();
  drawImageCanvas();
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}

/**
 * Draws a line using the recorded cursor positions.
 *
 * This line is used to mask the original image.
 */
function drawLineCanvas() {
  var minimumLineWidth = 25;
  var maximumLineWidth = 100;
  var lineWidthRange = maximumLineWidth - minimumLineWidth;
  var maximumSpeed = 50;

  lineCanvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, lineCanvas.width, lineCanvas.height);
  lineCanvasContext.lineCap = 'round';
  lineCanvasContext.shadowBlur = 30;
  lineCanvasContext.shadowColor = '#000';
  
  for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    var point = points[i];
    var previousPoint = points[i - 1];

    // Change line width based on speed
    var distance = getDistanceBetween(point, previousPoint);
    var speed = Math.max(0, Math.min(maximumSpeed, distance));
    var percentageLineWidth = (maximumSpeed - speed) / maximumSpeed;
    lineCanvasContext.lineWidth = minimumLineWidth + percentageLineWidth * lineWidthRange;

    // Fade points as they age
    var age = Date.now() - point.time;
    var opacity = (pointLifetime - age) / pointLifetime;
    lineCanvasContext.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, ' + opacity + ')';
    
    lineCanvasContext.beginPath();
    lineCanvasContext.moveTo(previousPoint.x, previousPoint.y);
    lineCanvasContext.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
    lineCanvasContext.stroke();
  }
}

/**
 * @param {{x: number, y: number}} a
 * @param {{x: number, y: number}} b
 * @return {number} The distance between points a and b
 */
function getDistanceBetween(a, b) {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a.x - b.x, 2) + Math.pow(a.y - b.y, 2));
}

/**
 * Draws the original image, masked by the line drawn in drawLineToCanvas.
 */
function drawImageCanvas() {
  // Emulate background-size: cover
  var width = imageCanvas.width;
  var height = imageCanvas.width / image.naturalWidth * image.naturalHeight;
  
  if (height < imageCanvas.height) {
    width = imageCanvas.height / image.naturalHeight * image.naturalWidth;
    height = imageCanvas.height;
  }

  imageCanvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, imageCanvas.width, imageCanvas.height);
  imageCanvasContext.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  imageCanvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
  imageCanvasContext.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
  imageCanvasContext.drawImage(lineCanvas, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-size: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background: url(https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg) 0 0 / cover;
}

img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/sunflowers-mr.jpg"/>
```

Comment: i dont get it to work even though i copy and paste it please explain to me how to copy the htm css and the last one yousay img url